# CSS3 animation transform rotate not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I found this animation in codepen.io. Everything is working fine but when I test it in firefox the animation is not working.

The code already has browser prefixes so I do not know what is not working in FF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

.loading {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:table;
    border-width:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -o-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
.style-1 {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#001e60 transparent
}
.style-2 {
    border-style:double;
    border-color:#001e60 transparent;
}
.style-3 {
    border-style:double;
    border-color:#001e60 #fff #fff;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        transform:rotate(359deg);
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="display: block;" class="loading-container">
        <span id="loadingIndicator" class="loading style-3"></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is having `.loading` use `display: table;` without actually specifying a width or height. Using a table like that to imply size is a bit hacky. Chrome is interpreting those dimensions differently than Firefox. It'd be best to explicitly give it a size using css. Try changing it to a block with a width and height like this:

```
.loading {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
  border-width:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

BIN: https://jsbin.com/nedanayopu/edit?html,output